# Enable LTE/4G on Samsung Galaxy J1 2016

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-j1

If a SM-J120H device with Android 5.1.1 shows "WCDMA/GSM (auto connect)" as its top "Mobile Networks=>Network Mode" option, is there any secret code that can enable a "LTE/WCDMA/GSM (auto)" mode instead?

In other devices it seems to involve dialing *#0011#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J120H is [not capable of LTE](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=9890&c=samsung_sm-j120hds_galaxy_j1_2016_duos__sm-j120hdd). The "H" suffix indicates HSPA-only.

Comment: What's that website? I can see it doesn't mention it in _Cellular Data Links_ but it does mention **LTE900 (B8)** in _Cellular Networks_

Comment: @LWC I noticed that too, but knowing the meaning of the H suffix, I'm pretty sure that's mistaken. Also, the built-in Spreadtrum SC7727SE is a WCDMA/HSPA+ platform. The F variant of the same phone seems to be powered by Exynos 3475 which is indeed LTE-capable.